# How to install a private Node.js package repository for a company intranet?

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, intranet

What is the recommended way of distributing packages to Node.js servers, running inside a company intranet? The problem is most servers cannot directly access [the npm registry](https://npmjs.org). Is it possible to install a private repo, sync it with the official one, and then sync the internal servers from here?

Comment: Have you looked at [this blog post](https://blog.caurea.org/2012/01/31/local-npm-registry-mirror.html)?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks! Here is another one: http://node-code.com/blog/?p=155

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to check your node_modules into your git repository (remove node_modules from .gitignore). Then, only your developer machines will need access to npm.org, and the servers will get the packages from your internal git repository.