# How to create smart LAN or company npm registry (node.js package repository)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, repository, package, npm

How to create **smart** local network or company npm registry (node.js package repository)?

It should be not mirror, but proxy that fetches only needed packages on required basis.
Just like in Java world maven repository managers like Nexus do.
Because main registry will grow, but only latest versions are usually needed.

Related to
[Can I run a private npm repository without replicating the public repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609131/can-i-run-a-private-npm-repository-without-replicating-the-public-repository)
[How to install a private Node.js package repository for a company intranet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361938/how-to-install-a-private-node-js-package-repository-for-a-company-intranet)

Docs reference:

[npm-registry(1) -- The JavaScript Package Registry](https://npmjs.org/doc/registry.html) [(github source)](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/blob/master/doc/cli/registry.md)

Answer (score 1):

If your company has a git repository you can simply specify your dependencies to the repository:

```
git://yourrepo/module.git#tagged_version
```

Also see https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html#examples

Comment: This is not answer to SMART PROXY. However, will this download dependencies that project depends on? I guess not.